# Laravel blade template <img src> not loading image after image upload upload (Failed to Load Resources Status 404)

Tags: laravel-5.8

I am uploading image from my blade template and the image is stored in storage/app/public/images which I have linked to public/storage/images using php artisan storage:link so it can be accessed publicly everything seems to work very fine on localhost but not on live server.

When I inspect the code I see this error message (GET http://domainname/storage/images/C1RWHeyLUokX8Hbz23bflhceAXzyEIHlqRDTl6UJ.jpeg 404 (Not Found)).

The image is uploaded and the path is stored correctly in my database, when I check the path I see the image in that path but is not loading on the web page.

I have tried loading the image like this image) }}"> but still not working.

//The blade template where I upload the image from

@csrf

//Route to where the image is uploaded
Route::post('/update_user', 'DoctorsController@UpdateUser');

//Controller to upload the image to server
    public function UpdateUser(Request $request){

```
    //capture the details sent by user for update
    $image = $request->file('image');

    //if the attachments is not empty upload the attachment to server
    if(!empty($image)){

       //$url = Storage::temporaryUrl(
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'jpeeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp');
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $files = explode('.', $file_name);
        $files1 = end($files);
        $file_extn = strtolower($files1);
        $filename1 = $files[0];
        $filename = strtolower($filename1);
        $file_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

          if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) == true){

            $imageurl = $image->store('images', 'public');


             $data = array();
             $data['image'] = $imageurl;

            //store path to database
            $dt = DB::table('profiles')
                 ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                 ->update($data);

            return view('edit-user')->with(['message' => 'success']);

          }else {

            return view('edit-user')->with(['message' => 'invalidimage']);

          }


       }

}
```

//When I try to display this image

//Route to fetch the image from the database
Route::get('/user_profile', 'DoctorsController@UserProfile');

//Controller to retrieve this image
public function UserProfile(Request $request){

```
        //fetch user details
        $profile=DB::table('profiles')
            ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();

        //return user profile when user is not doctor
        return view('user-profile')->with(['profile' => $profile]);
    }
```

//Blade template to display the image
@foreach($profile as $profiles)

image) ? asset('storage/'.$profiles->image) : asset('assets/img/image_placeholder.jpg')) }}" class="img-fluid mb-4" alt="Image placeholder" />

@endforeach

This code is expected to retrieve user image using the link stored on the database and display on a blade template, but but it doesn't display any image rather when I inspect the code I get this error message Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Instead of asset('storage/'.$profiles->image) try url('storage/'.$profiles->image)

Comment: Please check if image is accessable by url and check storage folder shortcut(symlink) is created in public forlder or not